# GRUB hangs / crashes with HDMI display

Tags: grub, crash, hdmi, vga

I just finished building my Klipper controlled 3d printer. As a host PC I'm using an Asrock J4105m motherboard running Debian 11. To interact with the control software I bought this touch display: https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B096ZSZFC8/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 The issue is that with this display connected to the PC via HDMI it won't boot. It hangs BEFORE GRUB is shown, the HDD activity LED is off, caps lock and numlock are unresponsive. The pc is just stuck right after the splash screen (which is correctly shown on the display, i can even access UEFI Setup without any problem). The PC boots normally on VGA. The PC boots normally on another HDMI screen. The PC boots normally if the offending display is plugged in even right after GRUB has appeared, the resolution is detected correctly and everythig works. This is the output of xrandr directly from the problematic display https://ibb.co/xGpZL7Q (the first display should be the VGA one that was connected at boot).

Do you any idea of what is going on? Can i somehow skip GRUB and directly bootstap debian? (the pc is dedicated to this 3d printer and i don't need other options).

ps: I already tryed with and without "nomodeset", with and without "quiet splash", with and without specifiying a resolution, i upgraded everything via apt upgrade. I'm out of ideas